# `awk -F_ "{print $1}"` not removing everything before the underscore in each line

Tags: awk, ls

I'm using Mac. I have a directory in which the files have names like `ABC_2016-06-08_09-23.csv`. I want to extract the part of each file name before the first underscore. I tried doing `ls | awk -F_ "{print $1}"` but I got back the full file names. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using double quotes instead of single quotes, so the correct is:

```
awk -F_ '{print $1}'
```

When you use double quotes, the shell expands `$1` to whatever is defined. If it is nothing, it expands to nothing and hence you get a simple `{print}` that prints the whole line.

$ echo "$1"

```
$ echo "hello_you" | awk -F_ "{print $1}"
hello_you
$ echo "hello_you" | awk -F_ '{print $1}'
hello
```

And see how we can make it useful on some way:

```
$ myvar="ueee"
$ echo "hello_you" | awk -F_ "{ueee=23; print $myvar}"
23
```